# ReactNative Firebase Firestore Crashes on Android

Tags: android, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, react-native-firebase

I'm trying to get [react-native-firebase](https://rnfirebase.io/) up and querying a firestore database in an android app. But whenever I try to query a collection, the app crashes with a very descriptive:

> Unfortunately, RNFirebaseStarter has stopped.

This is happening right from the [starter project](https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase-starter), using the firestore query code right out of [the Todo app tutorial](https://blog.invertase.io/getting-started-with-cloud-firestore-on-react-native-b338fb6525b9). And is happening both in an android simulator and on a device connected through USB.

There are no errors being reported anywhere that I can find. How would I even begin to debug this?

Following up, [here's a gist of the `adb logcat` output](https://gist.github.com/nicholasstephan/e608462405e3e00bd849546f4ffa8a16).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you still having an issue with this? Could you post logs from `adb logcat` so we can pinpoint the actual error?

Thanks

Comment: Yeah - I've run through the installation again, and am getting the same result. I've added a gist of the `logcat` output to the post above. It looks like there is an exception being thrown from `RNFirebaseFirestoreCollectionReference`, but I can't tell what the problem is. The same project runs perfectly on iOS.

Comment: Ah, I see the issue in your gist, `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown pattern character 'X'` was caused by a date parsing issue in a previous version, this has since been resolved, if you upgrade your RNFirebase version you should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

```
in your android/app/build.gradle file set     multiDexEnabled true

    android {
  //..

  defaultConfig {
    //..
    multiDexEnabled true  // needed for firestore:
  }`enter code here`
  //..
}
```